# issue with swift container and relative/absolute path

Tags: bash, openstack, openstack-swift

I wrote a script which uploaded some files from a VM cinderblock to a swift object store. Unfortunately, I used a relative path to specify the file to upload.

For example:

`$ swift upload container ../path/to/file.`

Well swift apparently decided to interpret this relative path as a literal, so now the location of the file in the container is literally `/../path/to/file`

Unfortunately, this means that I cant download the file from the object store, because swift tries to maintain the directory structure and attempts to create a ".." directory and errors out. I've tried escaping with \, casting as a literal, downloading the entire container, but nothing is working.

Has anyone ran into this problem, or have any ideas to help me figure how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do this from the parent directory:

```
$ swift upload container path/to/file
```

Or use `--object-name`:

```
$ cd path/to
$ swift upload container file --object-name path/to/file
```